# JSP useBean scope question

Tags: jsp, scope, javabeans

I have 4 JSP pages

- index.jsp - default index webpage. Index.jsp includes the build.jsp to initialize the web service as well as the header.jsp (to display the form with the dropdown element. Users can select a value from this form and submit the form to formControl.jsp.)
- build.jsp - This jsp is included in index.jsp before the HTML elements. It builds all of the necessary java beans and sets the values.
- headerBar.jsp - This jsp is included in index.jsp. It contains a logo image as well as a form with a dropdown element. This form submits to formControl.jsp. This headerBar.jsp page is included in the index.jsp and formControl.jsp pages for reusability.
- formControl.jsp - accepts the parameter from the form in headerBar.jsp and processes the value.

I have two useBean statements in build.jsp which instantiates a web service and my beans. Whenever I set their scope to "request", the dropdown element in headerBar.jsp displays all of the values I need. However, when I set the scope to "session", the dropdown element has no values.

I do not understand what is going on.
Could someone please explain?

Thankyou,
Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a servlet to add the values for the dropdown into session scope.  Something that knows about session has to manage it for you.